# ajax update multiple div

Tags: cakephp

In my application i need to update multiple divs.
we can give the div names in array. But i dont know how to render two ctp files in controller.

for one ctp $this->render('newctp','ajax');

I want to know how to update for two?

Answer (score 0):

Put the two .ctp files you need to render into elements (more info here).  Then, in your view, render both elements.  Like this:

myAjaxView.ctp

```
<?php $this->render('myFirstElement'); ?>
<?php $this->render('mySecondElement'); ?>
```

and you'd have two ctp files under views/elements (myFirstElement.ctp and mySecondElement.ctp) that would contain the html you'd like rendered.

Good luck

Comment: I don't think your "(more info here)" link got included in your response.